# Run time exception while starting an already stopped thread but no exception when resuming

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, if a thread is stopped, then it can't be started again without creating a new instance. Trying to start results in run time exception but trying to resume doesn't. Why is that so?

```
Thread t1  = new Thread();
t1.start();
t1.stop();
t1.start();
```

This results in exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:705)
    at ThreadEx.main(File.java:12)
```

But we use resume() instead of start(), no exception occurs? Surely, there is nothing to resume - so nothing will happen - but why no exception?

```
Thread t1  = new Thread();
t1.start();
t1.stop();
t1.resume(); // No exception
```

Comment: Don't use `Thread.stop()` or `Thread.resume()`. They are dangerous and deprecated. [Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the javadoc for [start()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) and [resume()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#resume()) methods.

This is what start's javadoc says:

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

So, when we start the thread, jvm checks whether the thread has already been started once and if yes, it throws `IllegalThreadStateException`.

Now, let's have a look at resume():

> If the thread is alive but suspended, it is resumed and is permitted
>   to make progress in its execution.

In our case, thread is not alive (because it has already been stopped) and hence, `resume` has no effect.

Also, as per javadoc, **it's not recommended** to use `stop`, `suspend` and `resume` methods. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)'s why.

Comment: Thanks for your input @AndyTurner, I have updated the answer.